# how to use a variable in url with flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am following a tutorial on youtube by the guy named 'thenewboston'.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27Fjrlx4s-o&index=2&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDi9F_slcQK7knjtO8TUvUs
Below is the code that i am using.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# @ signifies a decorator - way to wrap a function and modifying its behavior
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "this is the homepage"


@app.route('/tuna')
def tuna():
    return '<h2> tuna is good</h2>'


@app.route('/profile/<username>')
def profile():
     return "hey there %s" % username

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When i go to
http://127.0.0.1:5000/profile/bucky
i get the following error

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `username` argument in the function definition for `profile()`:

```
@app.route('/profile/<username>')
def profile(username):
    return "hey there %s" % username
```